# Query regarding geoindex package of Python

Tags: python, indexing, geolocation, geocoding

With reference to the simple use case of [geoindex package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geoindex/0.0.1), I am unable to get clarity regarding geo_index and index.

From what I understand

- geo_index is the object of class GeoGridIndex
- index is being populated with latitudes and longitudes before creating a tuple.

The [simpleUseCase.py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/geoindex/0.0.1) is as follows :

```
    import random
    from geoindex import GeoGridIndex, GeoPoint
        index = GeoGridIndex()
    for _ in range(10000):
        lat = random.random()*180 - 90
        lng = random.random()*360 - 180
        index.add_point(GeoPoint(lat, lng))
    center_point = GeoPoint(37.7772448, -122.3955118)
    for distance, point in index.get_nearest_points(center_point, 10, 'km'):
        print("We found {0} in {1} km".format(point, distance))
```

So, what is the actual purpose of the geo_index variable? When I compile this code, I get a NameError stating undefined index. Am I missing out on something here?

Answer (score 1):

The error in the code is being corrected in the following snippet :

```
 for _ in range(10000):
    lat = random.random()*180 - 90
    lng = random.random()*360 - 180
    geo_index.add_point(GeoPoint(lat, lng))
```

geo_index is the object of the class GeoGridIndex, which has member functions such as add_point and get_nearest_point. In the above snippet, you are populating the entire list with random (X,Y) or (Lat,Long) co-ordinates.